# create an object using forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Depending on the data returned by a graphql query, I want to create an object like this:

```js
const DATA = [
    {
        id: 'bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba',
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: 'Johann',
    },
    {
        id: '3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63',
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: 'Lars',
    },
    {
        id: '58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72',
        imageUrl: defaultUrl,
        name: 'Sarah',
    },
];
```

However, I don't understand how I can iterate through the data and create an object out of it. For instance, by doing this, I can extract all fristnames into an array:

```js
var friendNames = new Array();

if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
    data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.forEach((relation: UserRelation) => {
        friendNames.push(relation.relatedUser.firstName);
    });
}
```

However, apart from the first names, I also want to add the ids and a hardcoded link (which will be same for all items for now). But how can I get my data in a shape similar to const `DATA`

Comment: `friendNames.push({name:relation.relatedUser.firstName,other:'value'});`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to is create a new Array based on another.

For this special purpose, the function `map` is the most adapted (`map` is cousin of `forEach`).

For each entry of `userRelations` array, we will create a new entry in a brand new Array.

```js
const data = {
  users: {
    nodes: [{
      userRelations: [{
        relatedUser: {
          firstName: 'Johann',
        },
      }, {
        relatedUser: {
          firstName: 'Lars',
        },
      }, {
        relatedUser: {
          firstName: 'Paul',
        },
      }],
    }],
  },
};

const myFormattedData = data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.map(x => ({
  id: 'myId',
  imageUrl: 'myUrl',
  name: x.relatedUser.firstName,
}));

console.log(myFormattedData);
```

---

Alternative syntax :

```js
const data = {
  users: {
    nodes: [{
      userRelations: [{
        relatedUser: {
          firstName: 'Johann',
        },
      }, {
        relatedUser: {
          firstName: 'Lars',
        },
      }, {
        relatedUser: {
          firstName: 'Paul',
        },
      }],
    }],
  },
};

const id = 'myId';
const imageUrl = 'myUrl';

const myFormattedData = data.users.nodes[0].userRelations.map(({
  relatedUser: {
    firstName: name,
  },
}) => ({
  id,
  imageUrl,
  name,
}));

console.log(myFormattedData);
```